# Dependency Injection in the context of two simple classes

Tags: java, dependencies

I have been having issues grasping Dependency Injection(or let me say its benefit). So I decided to write two simple pieces of code of one without DI and the other with it.

So I have a class A

```
public class A {
    public void foo(){
        B b = new B();
        b.fooB();
    }
}
```

as can be seen above A depends on B, B which is

```
public class B {
    public void fooB(){
        Log.e("s", "y");
    }
}
```

and we can use A like

```
public void do(){
    A a = new A();
    a.foo();
}
```

But it's said that A should not simply initialize B because it depends on it, however we should have have a service that have some sort of contracts between the two classes. For Example, please if I am wrong kindly let me know

So lets have an interface BService

```
public interface BService {
    void fooB();
}
```

And B becomes DiB

```
public class DiB implements BService {
    @Override
    public void fooB(){
        Log.e("s", "y");
    }
}
```

And A becomes DiA

```
public class DiA {
    BService bService;

    public DiA(BService bService){
        this.bService = bService;
    }

    public void foo(){
        bService.fooB();
    }
}
```

and we can use A like

```
public void dIdo(){
        BService service = new diB();
        diA a = new diA(service);
        a.foo();
}
```

So I read benefits of DI are :

- Testable codes : Because I can actually test both codes in JUnit(I
  dont want to post the test here to avoid long question)
- Decoupling: Its said that if class B changes then A shouldn't be
  affected, and I cant grasp that because If i change fooB() in class B
  to fooB2(), i will have to change the override method in BService
  which in turn means i will have to change it in class A

Both codes seems to work fine and I cant fathom benefit of one over the other, only that the other is more complex. So please can you enlighten me more on the benefits in the context of this simple A and B classes. What am I not getting?

Answer (score 0):

on a first note, I don't agree with your "it's said that A should not simply initialize B because it depends on it".. because the same code worked for me in .NET

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A aobj = new A();
        aobj.foo();
    }
}
public class A {
    public void foo()
    {
        B bojb = new B();
        bojb.fooB();
        Console.WriteLine("From A.foo() ..");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
public class B {
    public void fooB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("From B.fooB() ..");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Apart of this, guess that you are confused with your fundamentals of Dependency Injection. The dependency word itself conveys the source of injection for any class.

1. First, the dependency can be identified during the instance of a class and the constructor is the first type.
2. Second, once the object is instantiated, before we call any method, there will be some assignments for the properties or public fields. Although it is optional, but, the sequence is as such. Thus, the second type.
3. Finally, the method injection.

Recommend you to read more before you make a case.

Comment: I am not making a case neither am I not saying DI is not good. I already said I just said i want to know the benefits. And thumbs up for highlighting the 3ways to go about DI.